# How to automatically set BoxConstraints dimensions while an image or a video is placed on it?

Tags: flutter

I'm going to create a page that looks like Telegram's channel page. I tried to make a card:

ChannelPostCard.dart:

```
class ChannelPostCard extends StatelessWidget {
  const ChannelPostCard({super.key, required this.channelPostModel});
  final ChannelPostModel channelPostModel;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Align(
      alignment: Alignment.centerRight,
      child: ConstrainedBox(
        constraints: BoxConstraints(
            maxWidth: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width - 45, minWidth: 180),
        child: Card(
          elevation: 1,
          shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8)),
          color: const Color.fromARGB(255, 204, 255, 230),
          margin: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 15, vertical: 5),
          child: Column(
            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
            children: [
              Image.asset(
                'assets/images/${channelPostModel.image}',
                height: 200,
              ),
              Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.only(
                    left: 25, right: 10, top: 5, bottom: 25),
                child: Text(
                  channelPostModel.text,
                  style: const TextStyle(
                    fontSize: 18,
                  ),
                ),
              ),
              Row(
                children: [
                  const SizedBox(
                    width: 5,
                  ),
                  Text(
                    channelPostModel.uploadDate,
                    style: const TextStyle(fontSize: 12, color: Colors.grey),
                  ),
                  const Padding(
                    padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 5),
                    child: Icon(
                      Icons.remove_red_eye,
                      size: 20,
                      color: Colors.grey,
                    ),
                  ),
                  Text(
                    channelPostModel.seenCount.toString(),
                    style: const TextStyle(fontSize: 12, color: Colors.grey),
                  )
                ],
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

[image]

I want to set the card's width equal to the width of the image (if the width is bigger than the "Max width" of the card, the max width will be applied.) and the image to be fitted in the card. The top right corner has also missed its roundness.
How can I fix my UI?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your first issue you need to set Row's `mainAxisSize` to `min`:

```
Row(
  mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min, // add this
  children: [
  const SizedBox(
    width: 5,
  ),
  ...
)
```

for your second issue you need set card's `clipBehavior` to `antiAlias`:

```
child: Card(
  clipBehavior: Clip.antiAlias, // add this
  elevation: 1,
  ...
)
```